# C# SqlDataAdapter Fill Inconsistent Results

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, fill

I would greatly appreciate some help with my `SqlDataAdapter` code below.
I am getting inconsistent results and am at a loss as to what the issue is.

**SCENARIO:**

This is a windows form project.

I have a routine that loops through a list of stations and calls the code below for each station.

The problem code executes the query (SQL Server) and fills a dataset with the returned rows.

Depending on what the station is up to, the returned rowcount will be >= 0 (typically 1 or 2).

**PROBLEM:**

The code does not always fill the dataset. Sometimes the dataset fills and sometimes it does not, or more accurately sometimes the rowcount = correct and sometimes rowcount = 0.

Currently, it is the same subset of stations that are not filling correctly.
There are no issues if rowcount is actually = 0.

**TROUBLESHOOTING SO FAR:**

1. The code does not throw any exceptions.
2. Looking at the parameters/ vars in the local window during step through I do not see any differences between stations that return correctly and those that do not.
3. The query itself does work without issue. I can execute the query in SSMS with the same parameters and I get the expected/ correct results in SSMS.
4. I do not see any difference in the SSMS query results between between stations that return/ fill correctly and those that do not (columns all have data, etc.).
5. My first thought was that I must have something amiss with these stations in the underlying tables, but again I see nothing out of place (no missing columns, nulls, etc.).
6. I have looked at quite a few posts regarding `SqlDataAdapter` and fill, but they appear to be dealing with all or nothing problems.

I would think if there was a problem with the code, the fill would fail all of the time.

I would also think if there was a problem with the query, the problem would be
present all of the time.

I would further think if there was a problem with the data, I would see something in the query results in SSMS.

**RESULTS:**

[image]

**CODE:**

```
string strSql = 
    @"SELECT
          ISNULL(a.ToolGroupId, 0) AS ToolGroupId, ISNULL(a.PartId, 0) AS PartId, 
          ISNULL(a.CycleCount, 0) AS CycleCount, ISNULL(a.BDT, 0) AS BDT, 
          start.starttime, endx.endtime,
          ISNULL(start.ProgName, 'none') AS Program, ISNULL(a.gName, 'none') AS gName, 
          ISNULL(a.ProductionMetrics, 1) AS ProductionMetrics 
      FROM
          (SELECT 
               MIN(datetime) AS starttime, ProgName 
           FROM
               V_CycleTime 
           WHERE 
               eocr_no = @stationId 
               AND datetime >= @startTime 
               AND datetime < @endtime 
           GROUP BY
               ProgName) AS start 
      LEFT JOIN
          (SELECT 
               MAX(datetime) AS endtime, ProgName
           FROM
               V_CycleTime 
           WHERE 
               eocr_no = @stationId 
               AND datetime >= @startTime 
               AND datetime < @endtime 
           GROUP BY 
               ProgName) AS endx ON (endx.ProgName = start.ProgName) 
      LEFT JOIN
          (SELECT 
               ISNULL(p.ToolGroupId, 0) AS ToolGroupId, 
               ISNULL(p.PartId, 0) AS PartId, 
               COUNT(ID) AS CycleCount, 
               AVG(Expected_Ct) AS BDT, 
               Program, p.gName, p.ProductionMetrics 
           FROM 
               V_CycleTime 
           LEFT JOIN 
               (SELECT 
                    ToolGroupId, Program, PartId, t.gName, t.ProductionMetrics 
                FROM 
                    PartsToPrograms 
                LEFT JOIN 
                    (SELECT ID, gName, ProductionMetrics 
                     FROM ToolGroups) t ON (t.ID = PartsToPrograms.ToolGroupId) 
                WHERE 
                    StationId = @stationId 
                    AND IsActive = 1) p ON (p.Program = V_CycleTime.ProgName) 
           WHERE 
               eocr_no = @stationId 
               AND datetime >= @startTime 
               AND datetime < @endtime 
           GROUP BY 
               p.ToolGroupId, p.PartId, Program, p.gName, p.ProductionMetrics) AS A ON (a.Program = start.ProgName) 
      WHERE 
          a.ToolGroupID IS NOT NULL 
      ORDER BY 
          start.starttime;";

// retrieve the dataset
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
string connetionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connString"].ConnectionString;

using (var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(strSql, connetionString))
{
    try
    {
        adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stationId", GlobalVars.stationId);
        adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startTime", GlobalVars.currentHourStartTime);
        adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endTime", GlobalVars.currentHourEndTime);

        adapter.Fill(ds);
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        SimpleLogger.SimpleLog.Log(ex);
        return;
    }
}

// test row count               
int rowCount = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;

if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
{
    //do this
}
else
{
    //do that
}
```

Comment: My guess is that `AddWithValue` is your problem: https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/

Comment: You could have a look at SQL Profiler in order to see what data types `AddWithValue` infers for the parameters.

Comment: @Ian I revised my AddWithValue statements based on the link you provided (thanks for that). Unfortunately the results did not change.

Comment: @Christian I am not very familiar with SQL Profiler, but I did get a trace going and I still do not see a difference between results: CORRECT=> N'@stationId int,@startTime datetime,@endTime datetime',@stationId=3,@startTime='2020-12-16 09:30:00',@endTime='2020-12-16 10:30:00'                      INCORRECT=>N'@stationId int,@startTime datetime,@endTime datetime',@stationId=42,@startTime='2020-12-16 09:30:00',@endTime='2020-12-16 10:30:00'

Comment: Now that you have these traces, have you tried to run these exact queries (using the perameters and everything as of the traces) in SSMS? If yes, did they return the same results as when called from C# (i.e. Station 3: correct, Station 42: Incorrect)?

Comment: I must be doing something wrong. When I take the complete TextData contents (starting with exec sp_executesql and ending with the parameters) into SSMS nothing returns. If I remove the sp_executesql trimmings and declare the parameters using the TextData values (copy/paste) the query executes with the same correct/ incorrect results. Sorry to be so dense, but this is new territory for me.